# Google Apps Script Apps Suddenly Performing Slowly/Erroring

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-apps, nosql

Is anyone else having performance issues with Apps Script Apps?

I have 9 apps that suddenly started performing very slowly on Friday. The common link between them seems to be ScriptDB although I am not sure that this is the issue. I wonder if this has anything to do with ScriptDB being deprecated at the end of this year?﻿

I am seeing the following error far more frequently than before:

`Service invoked too many times in a short time: scriptdb rateMax. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls.`

Thanks in advance

Stuart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes ive seen it too in my scripts. Lately scriptDb has apparently gotten more strict about rate limits.
I have a script running continuously over 1 year and got that same error twice this week, and none for many months.